# Can't fit Poisson to histogram in

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, poisson

I've looked at a bunch of examples on here and tried using snippets of other codes, but they're not working for me. I have 4 data sets, but I'll include just one here. My professor told me that the data appeared to be Poisson distributed, so I am trying to fit a Poisson to a histogram of the data. Here is my code:

```
######## Poisson fit ########

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import factorial

data = data59[4]
entries,bin_edges,patches = plt.hist(data59[4],60,[1,10],normed=True)
bin_middles = 0.5*(bin_edges[1:]+bin_edges[:-1])

def poisson(k, lamb):
    return np.exp(-lamb)*(lamb**k)/factorial(k)

popt,pcov = curve_fit(poisson,bin_middles,entries)

x = np.linspace(1,10,100)

plt.plot(x,poisson(x,*popt))

plt.show()
```

[image: link to plot]

I tried plotting other distributions on top of the histogram like normal and Rayleigh using `scipy.stats` instead of `curve_fit`. Those kind of worked only because they have a scale parameter, which `scipy.stats.poisson` doesn't. The distribution for this comes out looking exactly the same as the `curve_fit`. I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Perhaps the data is not even Poisson distributed!

Thanks for helping!!

Update: The data is IceCube data from the TXS 0506+056 blazar. [I used SkyDrive to get a URL for the file. I hope it works](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ao_-sSnW8rFwac8jdgX6QfFUfPQ). The first column is the modified Julian day and the last column is the log of the energy proxy. I am using the last column. I have null and alternative hypotheses surrounding this data and am using maximum likelihood estimation (from a certain distribution, Poisson in my first case) to analyze the data.

Also, here is where I got the data: https://icecube.wisc.edu/science/data/TXS0506_point_source

Comment: If your data were to be an infinite sample they would quite fit into your distribution (if they are indeed poisson), but since you have just a finite number of them you get these results.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Why is this the case? What does an infinite sample allow? I've seen similar codes where people generate random data and the fit to the histogram is quite good, but these are not infinite samples. Do you have suggestions as to what I could use instead?

Comment: Ok, let's start from the beginning: in the distribution the `y` value is the distribution density. What is the `y` value of your histogram?

Comment: FYI: The [maximum likelihood estimate for the Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Maximum_likelihood) is simply the mean of the random sample.  You could use that instead of `curve_fit`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Why bother when the data clearly don't meet the minimal requirements to be Poisson?

Comment: @corgiworld, can you share a raw data set, and perhaps explain what the data is?

Comment: @Luca Cappelletti The y value of the histogram is the count of energy values that fall within a certain interval.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser I am actually using the maximum likelihood estimate for my project, and this is what I found (about the mean). I did not think of using this instead of curve_fit.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser I have updated my post to include the data.

Comment: Please do not use an image file for your data sample, that's useless if we want to try fits of the data on our own.

Comment: @pjs I tried making a URL for the file and put it in my original post. I hope you can access it. Sorry for the screenshot.

Comment: @corgiworld The URL you provided requires me to register to download the data.  I declined to do so.  Your question should be self contained.

Comment: I used distribution fitting in JMP with the sample data you've linked to.  Top choices seem to be a Johnson SI distribution or a LogNormal distribution.  It's pretty ambiguous given how little data there is.  Given that column 5 is described as the log of the measurement, I'd recommend trying LogNormal fits.

Comment: Okay, I will try these distributions. Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The data presented in your histogram [does **not** have a Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Assumptions:_When_is_the_Poisson_distribution_an_appropriate_model?).  The Poisson is a counting distribution (what's the probability of getting 0, 1, 2,... observations per unit of time or space), its support is the positive integers. Your histogram clearly shows that you have fractional values, since the spikes are different non-zero heights at non-integer locations.

Comment: Interesting. I had previously read through the page you provided, but I don't think I realized this about the integer values. Thanks for the insight.